# How to delete head of a list of int*int in ocaml

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

Im trying to remove the head of list of type (int*int) using List.filter but i get an error.
This is what i am trying to do:

```
List.filter (fun (i,j) -> List.tl <> List.hd) lst
```

Comment: What's the error? Also you're just comparing two functions since you're not applying any arguments to them. Nothing about this makes any sense. Just use `List.tl lst` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to do that with `List.filter`? It's not its purpose. If you are absolutely certain the head has no duplicate in the list, you could do

```
List.filter (fun u -> u <> List.hd lst) lst
```

But note `List.tl lst` will do it better.